# cannot convert parameter 1 from 'PrintVisitor *const ' to 'Visirot &'

Tags: c++, design-patterns, composite, typeconverter, visitor-pattern

I used two design pattern Composite and Visitor. I have no problem with Composite.But when he began writing derived classes for input and output got some errors, solution which I did never found. Although in reality, and if everything is *InputVisitor* done so remained only *PrintVisitor* and *main()*.

Here is my code:

**UPD:** I rewrite some parts of code. Now I have no erros, but it only open terminal and nothind doing...

P.S. Maybe I did not properly implement of patterns. Someone has a better idea?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class BaseComponent {
public:
    virtual void add(BaseComponent *)=0;
    virtual void accept(class Visitor &)=0;
};

class Card :public BaseComponent {
public:
    Card (string bookName, vector<string> authors, int year): _bookName(bookName), _authors(authors), _year(year) {}

    string getBookName() const {
        return _bookName;
    }
    vector<string> getAuthors() const {
        return _authors;
    }
    int getYear() const {
        return _year;
    }

    void setBookName(string bookName) {
        _bookName = bookName;
    }
    void setAuthors(vector<string> authors) {
        copy(authors.begin(), authors.end(), _authors.begin());
    }
    void setYear(int year) {
        _year = year;
    }

    void add(BaseComponent *){}
    void accept(class Visitor &);
private:
    string _bookName;
    vector<string> _authors;
    int _year;
};

class Folder :public BaseComponent {
public:
    Folder(): _folderName(""), _parentFolder("") {}
    Folder(string parentFolder): _folderName(""), _parentFolder(parentFolder) {}

    string getFolderName() const {
        return _folderName;
    }
    string getParentName() const {
        return _parentFolder;
    }
    vector<BaseComponent*> getSubFolders() const {
        return _subFolders;
    }

    void setFolderName(string folderName) {
        _folderName = folderName;
    }
    void setParentFolder(string parentFolder) {
        _parentFolder = parentFolder;
    }

    void add(BaseComponent *component) {
        _subFolders.push_back(component); 
    }
    void accept(class Visitor &);
private:
    string _folderName;
    string _parentFolder;
    vector<BaseComponent*> _subFolders;
};

class Visitor {
public:
    virtual void visitCard(Card *)=0;
    virtual void visitFolder(Folder *)=0;
};

void Card::accept(class Visitor &visitor) {
    visitor.visitCard(this);
}

void Folder::accept(class Visitor &visitor) {
    visitor.visitFolder(this);
}

class InputVisitor :public Visitor {
public:
    InputVisitor(string file): _file(file){}

    void setFile(string file) {
        _file = file;
    } 

    void visitCard(Card *){}
    void visitFolder(Folder *folder){
        ifstream input(_file);

        string folderName;
        getline(input, folderName);
        folder->setFolderName(folderName);

        string fileName;
        while (!input.eof()) {
            input >> fileName;
            if (fileName == "----") {
                break;
            } else {
                Folder *subFolder = new Folder(folderName);
                InputVisitor *inputVisitor = new InputVisitor(fileName);
                subFolder->accept(*inputVisitor);
                folder->add(subFolder);
            }
        }
        while (!input.eof()) {
            string name, tempAuthor;
            vector<string> authors;
            int n, year;

            input >> name;
            input >> n;
            for (int i = 0; i<n; ++i) {
                input >> tempAuthor;
                authors.push_back(tempAuthor);
            }
            input >> year;
            Card *subBook = new Card(name, authors, year);
            folder->add(subBook);
        }
        input.close();
    }
private:
    string _file;
};

class PrintVisitor :public Visitor {
public:
    PrintVisitor(string outputFile): _outputFile(outputFile) {}

    void setOutputFile(string outputFile) {
        _outputFile = outputFile;
    }

    void visitFolder(Folder *folder) {
        ofstream output(_outputFile);
        output << folder->getFolderName() << endl << "\t";

        vector<BaseComponent*> subFolders = folder->getSubFolders();
        vector<BaseComponent*>::iterator it;
        for (it=subFolders.begin(); it!=subFolders.end(); ++it) {
            (*it)->accept(*this);
        }

        output.close();
    }
    void visitCard(Card *card) {
        ofstream output(_outputFile);
        output << "Book: " << card->getBookName() << endl
            << "Author(s): ";
        vector<string> authors = card->getAuthors();
        for (vector<string>::iterator it=authors.begin(); it!=authors.end(); ++it) {
            output << *it << " ";
        }
        output << endl << "Year: " << card->getYear();

        output.close();
    }
private:
    string _outputFile;
};


int main() {
    Folder root;
    root.accept(*(new InputVisitor("root.txt")));
    root.accept(*(new PrintVisitor("output.txt")));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You did spot the "Visirot" spelling mistake, right?

Comment: Learn C++ from a book. Even if this compiled, you'd get lots of run-time errors.

Comment: The *repeated* `Visirot` spelling mistake.

Answer (score 0):

In this code:

```
InputVisitor *input;
input->setFile("root.txt");
root->accept(input);  //Here
```

InputVisitor is a *input. Your accept function takes a reference to a visitor. Change it to:

```
root->accept(*input);  //Here
```

and all will be fine, aside from the typo I mentioned in the comment.

If you remove all the `class` in front of names for classes, the compiler will tell you when there is a misspelled class name. Otherwise, it will just treat it as "there'll be a class named `Visirot` at some point in the future, and I don't really care what's in it right now.

Comment: Thanks, next time I will do as you said. But unfortunely program doesn't work... Can you check my edited code in my question?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the declaration of `BaseComponent::accept`:

```
virtual void accept(class Visirot &)=0;
```

Here is the call:

```
root->accept(input);  //Here
```

Here is the declaration of `input`:

```
InputVisitor *input;
```

So, first, the declaration of `BaseComponent::accept` apparently has a typo; `Visirot` should probably be `Visitor`.

Second, `accept` takes a `Visitor&`, but it's being called with an `InputVisitor*`. `InputVisitor` is derived from `Visitor, so`InputVisitor*`is convertible to`Visitor*`and`InputVisitor&`is convertible to`Visitor&`, but there is no conversion from a pointer-to-type into a reference-to-type. So either change`BaseComponent::accept` to take a pointer or change the call to pass a reference.

Answer (score 0):

### First problem.

Assuming the typo `Visirot` is fixed, then at line 152 you have

```
subFolders[i]->accept(this); //Here some probrem
```

which passes a pointer to T where a T is expected.

Just dereference that pointer:

```
subFolders[i]->accept(*this);
```

### Second problem.

Applying the same fixes in the main program would be *wrong*:

```
int main() {
    BaseComponent *root;
    InputVisitor *input;
    input->setFile("root.txt");
    root->accept(*input);  //Here
    PrintVisitor *output;
    output->setOutputFile("output.txt");
    root->accept(output); //And here
    return 0;
}
```

This dereferences uninitialized pointers, which yields **Undefined Behavior**.

Don't do that.

Rewrite it as e.g.

```
int main() {
    Folder root;
    InputVisitor input;
    input.setFile("root.txt");
    root.accept(input);  //Here
    PrintVisitor output;
    output.setOutputFile("output.txt");
    root.accept(output); //And here
}
```

(and possibly replace `Folder` with whatever concrete class you want there.)

### Third problem.

At line 144 you're assigning to a stream:

```
_outputFile = ofstream(outputFile);
```

where `_outputFile` is a member of type `ofstream`, and `outputFile` is a `string`.

This uses a C++11 feature (rvalue assignment of streams) that g++ didn't implement as of version 4.7.1.

Presumably the idea is to close `_outputFile` and reopen it: just do that, and the code will be much more portable:

```
// Add failure checking:
_outputFile.close();
_outputFile.open( outputFile );
```

Also, more descriptive naming would be good…

### General problem set in the given code.

Compiling the above yields a number of warnings about signed/unsigned comparisons and unused local variables. Fix all that. Build at highest practical warning level, `-Wall` with g++ and `/W4` with Visual C++, and make it compile cleanly.

### Logic errors & testing.

Even when it compiles cleanly, there can and usually will remain logic errors. To root out those, devise a set of *exactly reproducible* tests, complete with any necessary test data.

Comment: Thank you very much. I corrected most of the errors which you have said and just rewrote the code. Now compiler see no errors, but just a terminal opens and nothing happens..